# How to implement Resolver-Inheritance with Type-GraphQL, TypeORM, and dependency injection

Tags: dependency-injection, factory, typeorm, typegraphql

I am trying to extend upon the Type-GraphQL provided example of resolvers-inheritance except replace the static data with a TypeORM repository.

Here is how the PersonResolver extends the ResourceResolver and how it passes the `persons` array as the second argument of the ResourceResolver constructor.

```
const persons: Person[] = [
  {
    id: 1,
    name: "Person 1",
    age: 23,
    role: PersonRole.Normal,
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    name: "Person 2",
    age: 48,
    role: PersonRole.Admin,
  },
];

@Resolver()
export class PersonResolver extends ResourceResolver(Person, persons) {
   ...
}
```

Inside the ResourceResolver

```
export function ResourceResolver<TResource extends Resource>(
  ResourceCls: ClassType<TResource>,
  resources: TResource[],
) {
  const resourceName = ResourceCls.name.toLocaleLowerCase();

  // `isAbstract` decorator option is mandatory to prevent multiple registering in schema
  @Resolver(_of => ResourceCls, { isAbstract: true })
  @Service()
  abstract class ResourceResolverClass {
    protected resourceService: ResourceService<TResource>;

    constructor(factory: ResourceServiceFactory) {
      this.resourceService = factory.create(resources);
    }
...
}
```

And in the ResourceServiceFactory

```
@Service()
export class ResourceServiceFactory {
  create<TResource extends Resource>(resources?: TResource[]) {
    return new ResourceService(resources);
  }
}

export class ResourceService<TResource extends Resource> {
  constructor(protected resources: TResource[] = []) {}

    getOne(id: number): TResource | undefined {
    return this.resources.find(res => res.id === id);
}
```

I would like to know the best way to implement the ResourceResolver but instead of static data I would like to pass a repository from TypeORM.

Here is the original example - https://github.com/MichalLytek/type-graphql/tree/master/examples/resolvers-inheritance.

Any help or advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'd have to do something funky like this in your resolver functions:

```
function createBaseResolver<T extends BaseEntity>(suffix: string, objectTypeCls: T) {
    @Resolver({ isAbstract: true })
    abstract class BaseResolver {  
      @Query(type => [objectTypeCls], { name: `getAll${suffix}` })
      async getA(@Arg("id", type => Int) id: number): Promise<T> {
          let beCastedObj = (<typeof BaseEntity> objectTypeCls.constructor); // https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/5677
          return beCastedObj.findOne({ where: { id:id } }) as Promise<T>;
      }
    }
  
    return BaseResolver;
  }
```

in another file...

```
const PersonBaseResolver = createBaseResolver("person", Person);

@Resolver(of => Person)
export class PersonResolver extends PersonBaseResolver {
  // ...
}
```

EDIT: OP asked if he thought this is a good pattern in the comments. I'm just starting to learn this, so don't take my word as gospel. However. I encountered trouble when taking the next step: defining custom arguments. If you use custom classes for the @Args() (recommended as it can auto-validate), then typescript/typegraphql NEEDS that info at compile time. You can keep that parent's resolvers as-is if these args will not change across any of the children, but if they change you need a way to pass in custom arguments.

I accomplished this by moving the resolver decorators to the children.

Example Parent:

```
abstract class BaseUserCreatedEntityResolver {

    async get(args: any, ctx: any): Promise<T> {
      this.checkForLogin(ctx);
      let beCastedObj = (<typeof UserCreatedEntity>objectTypeCls.constructor);
      args = Object.assign(args, { userCreator: ctx.req.session.userId })
      let a =  beCastedObj.findOne({ where: args }) as any;
      return a;
    }

    async getAll(args: any, ctx: any): Promise<T> {
      this.checkForLogin(ctx);
      let beCastedObj = (<typeof UserCreatedEntity>objectTypeCls.constructor);
      args = Object.assign(args, { userCreator: ctx.req.session.userId });
      beCastedObj.create(args);
      return beCastedObj.find({ where: args }) as any;
    }

    async add(args:any, ctx: any): Promise<T> {
      this.checkForLogin(ctx);
      let beCastedObj = (<typeof UserCreatedEntity>objectTypeCls.constructor);
      args = Object.assign(args, { userCreator: ctx.req.session.userId });
      let entity = await beCastedObj.create(args)[0];
      await entity.save();
      return entity as any;
    }

    async delete(args:any, ctx: any): Promise<T> {
      this.checkForLogin(ctx);
      let entity = await this.get(args,ctx);
      await entity.remove();
      return new Promise(()=>true);
    }

    async update(args:any, ctx: any): Promise<T> {
      this.checkForLogin(ctx);
      let entity = await this.get(args,ctx);
      delete args['userCreator'];// this should've been filtered out in child param definition, but adding it here just in case

      Object.assign(entity,args);
      await entity.save();
      return entity;
    }

    checkForLogin(ctx:any){
      if(!ctx.req.session.userId) throw new Error("User not logged in");
    }

  }
```

Example Child:

```
@ArgsType()
class GetAllArgs {
  @Field()
  date:Date;
}

//...

@Query(() => Entity)
async getAllEntitiesName(@Args() args :GetAllArgs, @Ctx() ctx: any) {
  return super.get(args,ctx);
}
```

I quite like this paradigm. And if I ever have a function that doesn't change across all the children resolvers, I will create that function and decorate it in the parent. For that reason, I am leaving the parent as a customizable function-class, instead of just a basic class.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer my question. If you are experienced with TypeGraphQL and TypeORM do you think this patter is worth implementing? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: My pleasure :). The answer was too long to your question so i edited my answer above.

Comment: Wow this is a really cool paradigm! I understand the concept (thanks to your explanation) but still doubt myself with the implementation. In your opinion do you think that I should pursue this paradigm or simply repeat myself in my resolvers - considering I have less than 10 entities in my application.

Comment: I'm basically just using a parent class. It helps cut out a lot of code from the children (stay DRY). And if any child needs a custom resolver, just don't use the `super` call. You can do it! Remove the confusing TypeGraphQL parent resolver stuff and just make it a normal JS class. Then copy+paste my code (removing the session/login stuff if you don't need it) and put it in the parent. I went ahead and copied in all my parent functions, hopefully that helps.

Comment: Another thing you can do is just start writing the child classes without a parent, and then when you get frustrated with the copy+paste switch to using a parent. If you never get frustrated then you may not need to switch! Reduces "Premature optimization" [of code]